# Detect Keyboard Input Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-input, keyboard-events

I have a simple question, although it's harder than it seems; I couldn't find the answer on the interwebs :O

I'm writing a script in Matlab. What I want to do is the following:

- When I press the esc key, I want a helpdialogue to pop up, so my script pauses. (So when I press esc, I want to stop the whole script to run so that the car (which im writing the script for) stops driving)

How do I do this? How can I say to Matlab: When I press esc, do this...

Thanks for your time guys!

EDIT: It's no option to implement something which awaits the keypress. Im writing a script for a driving car. It just has to drive around basically, but when I press esc for example, it should stop driving. So the script just has to run, untill I press the esc key; then the script has to pause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a matlab figure you can define a `'KeyPressFcn'` that works similar to do what you ask.

If you are in the console you have to work around that matlab is single threaded. Basically you need to halt the program flow to check for key presses.

btw - also when you use `'KeyPressFcn'` you will need to make some pauses so that Matlab will check if anything has happened.

btw2 - I should also add during this pauses Matlab will not only read your key presses - but also do some housekeeping such as redrawing its window and stuff.

Comment: Well the problem is that I can't pause matlab in order to press a key. My idea was, that when I press a key (i.e. esc), the matlab script pauses(for safety reasons btw). But if I have to pause matlab in order to press a key in order to pause the script, it's not that useful. Any other idea:)?

Comment: You don't have to pause long and it's not required to pause exactly at the moment (usually you hold the key *much* longer). Sprinkling a few `pause(0.01)` through the code will do the trick - best combined with a non-blocking read. Within Matlab you will not get around pause. The only key combination that will get through to you is Ctrl-C - which is not that useful for control the flow.

Comment: Well you *could* try to implement some multithreading on top of matlab. But usually it's easier to implement the algorithm in a language that already supports that. (also it will be quite slow in Matlab). Or wait till the Matlab language supports it - but we are talking years or even decades here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. In the end I decided to make a GUI, in which I used the KeyPressFcn. And it worked :)

Answer (score 6):

`KeyPressFcn` is good because it forces you to write *event-driven code*. Which is generally a good idea! However, if `KeyPressFcn` doesn't seem right for you, for example if you must keep running in a loop, and you just want to **poll** whether a key has been pressed, I found this solution buried in the matlab website:

```
get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter')
```

Then you could set this property to a blank, and poll it as required.
e.g:

```
finish=false;
set(gcf,'CurrentCharacter','@'); % set to a dummy character
while ~finish
  % do things in loop...

  % check for keys
  k=get(gcf,'CurrentCharacter');
  if k~='@' % has it changed from the dummy character?
    set(gcf,'CurrentCharacter','@'); % reset the character
    % now process the key as required
    if k=='q', finish=true; end
  end
end
```

This worked well for me in 2014b. The downside is that the graphics window needs to be focused to receive the key events.

Comment: I like this. I find myself wanting to capture a number of keystrokes (displaying a series of images, capture yes/no response). Do you have any idea how you could prevent the keystrokes from being echoed to the console?

Answer (score 1):

I frequently ran into similar use cases and typically preferred to react to joystick buttons because of the more convenient interface provided by vrjoystick. However, I recently wrote a library that provides a similar interface for keyboard inputs.

```
% Pause on ESC
kb = HebiKeyboard();
while true
    state = read(kb);
    if state.ESC
      % PAUSE DRIVING
    else
      % DRIVE CAR
    end
end
```

It's non-blocking and doesn't require focus on any particular figure.

File Exchange: http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61306-hebirobotics-matlabinput

Github: https://github.com/HebiRobotics/MatlabInput

Answer (score 0):

I had a related task once, and i did it with [`getkey`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7465-getkey) form matlab file exchange.
Basicly you will want to have it listen for ascii 1B (27 decimal)

if `getkey` does not solve your problem you can still have a look at its code and maybe find the line that will do the trick for you.

Comment: How does getkey actually work? It's stated that getkey will wait for keyboard input. With waiting, does it mean the script is paused? Because that's not what I would like to have. I want to implement that  when I press a key, the script pauses (so no pause in order to press a key). Do you understand what I want? Is this possible with getkey?