# How to delete characters as they are typed into MATLAB command line

Tags: matlab, command-line

I am using my keyboard to run an application in MATLAB, where each keypress is handled differently depending on the number or letter pressed. To recognize keypresses I'm using the HebiRobotics library discussed here:

[Detect Keyboard Input Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145294/detect-keyboard-input-matlab#)

While running the program, hundreds of keypresses are required, each of which types a character in the command line, after the >>. Is there any way to delete these characters as they are typed so the command line remains clear? I've tried fprintf('%c',8) to backspace, but this applies to the previous *executed* command, not the characters on the current line.

To be honest, this isn't terribly important, but having the characters appear is ugly, takes a few extra clicks to delete, and is one of those little things that is driving me crazy.

Comment: Couldn't you just put `clc` in your callback?

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't address your issue? [How to clear the last line in the command window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8825796/52738)

Comment: @Suever - I'm printing instructions as the code runs, so I don't want to clear the entire command window.  Just the newly typed characters (appearing after >>)

Comment: @gnovice - If I'm understanding that link correctly, these suggestions only work for text that is being printed to the command window.  My code isn't actually printing the keypresses, but they appear after the >> as each key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This answer by 'Oleg Komarov' seems to be relevant -[Clearing text typed with input() from command history](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/133581-clear-text-typed-with-input-from-the-command-history)